# Is there a way for a python script to "know" if it is being piped to?

Tags: python, pipe

#### myscript.py

```
import sys
if something_to_read_from_stdin_aka_piped_to:
    cmd = sys.stdin.read()
    print(cmd)
else:
    print("standard behavior")
```

#### Bash example:

```
echo "test" | python myscript.py
```

If it is not being piped to, it would hang.

What is the way to know if the script should or should not read from stdin; I'm hoping there's something obvious other than a command line argument for the script.

Comment: @dan1111 Not important. Updated example with some pseudocode.

Comment: It's simply something that needs to be documented.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible, I have modified your example to achieve this.

```
import sys
import os
if not os.isatty(0):
    cmd = sys.stdin.read()
    print(cmd)
else:
    print("standard behavior")
```

As we know 0 is file descriptor for input to program. isatty is test to check file descriptor refer to terminal or not.
As pointed out by other user above approach will tell whether program is reading from terminal or not. However above programming solves the purpose of question but still there is room to improve. We can have another solution which will just detect if program is reading from pipe or not.

```
import sys
import os
from stat import S_ISFIFO

if S_ISFIFO(os.fstat(0).st_mode):
    print("Reading from pipe")
    cmd = sys.stdin.read()
    print(cmd)
else:
    print("not reading from pipe")
```

Comment: I think the test is "`if not os.isatty(0)`", but that is indeed it!

Comment: This doesn't detect that the program reads from a pipe; it detects that it is reading from a terminal or not. `echo foo | script` and `script < foo` would both have `os.isatty(0)` return `False`.

Comment: @chepner I have Edited my answer with new code which will detect if program is reading from pipe or not.